# How can I add two arrays of numbers to each other like a matrix?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$a = [1 , 2, 3 ,4];
$b = [5 , 6 , 7 , 8];
$c = $a + $b ;
```

How can i find `$c` that i is equal to `$c = [6 , 8 , 10 , 12];` ?

Comment: if i understand you it would be like this `$c = [$a, $b]`

Comment: in this case i want to get variable c that is [6,8,10,12]
@NickParsons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be to use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and pass through your two arrays after the callback function like so:

```
$c = array_map(function($x, $y) {
  return $x + $y;
}, $a, $b);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 8 [2] => 10 [3] => 12 )
```

For an approach that should work for *N* arrays, you can use the splat operator (...):

```
$arrs = [$a, $b]; // [a1, a2, ..., an];
$c = array_map(function(...$nums) {
    return array_sum($nums);
}, ...$arrs);
```

Comment: Although slower than a `foreach` for two arrays, this is definitely the easy way to write the code for `n` arrays.

Comment: @Nick thanks, Nick. I like the `foreach` approach as well as it is easy to understand what is going on with that approach. It is, however, difficult to extend for an arbitary number of arrays 

Comment: I posted that exact same solution (the "dynamic" one) while you were editing, so deleted mine + upvoted! If you're in PHP7.4 you can even go: `$sum = array_map(fn(...$nums) => array_sum($nums), ...$arrs);`

Comment: @Jeto thanks Jeto, I guess we had the same idea. I like the idea of using the arrow functions; looks much cleaner

Comment: @NickParsons yeah - this is what happens when I answer the question as written! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Achieve This By Writing Simple Function :

```
function add($matrix1, $matrix2){
    if (is_numeric($matrix1) && is_numeric($matrix2)){
        return $matrix1 + $matrix2;
    }else{
        $res = $matrix1; // Create A Matrix With Same Dimensions
        for ($i=0; $i<count($matrix1); $i++)
            $res[$i] = add($matrix1[$i], $matrix2[$i]);  
        return $res;
    }
}

print_r(add([1, 2, 3, 4],[4, 3, 2, 1]));
//Output Will Be :
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 5 [2] => 5 [3] => 5 )
```

You Can Strobe On Any Matrix Of Any Dimension And You'll Get Matrices Of 1 Dimension Lower And This Method Finally Leads To A Matrix of [1 x 1] And Using Recursive Function We Can Add Up Each Parsed Matrix Individually.